# Windows azure: Security Concerns

Tags: windows, azure

I am concern about the security of the data and application on Windows Azure... I read in a book that The windows azure provides security through service-level agreement.

Can anyone tell me about the What kind of authentication mechanisms used to protect my data.
How Microsoft provides these securities...

Comment: What do you mean by "security"? Security guarantees of the data stored on Azure? Authorisation controls for people accessing the service? Or something else?

Comment: Service level agreement (or SLA) has nothing to do with security, those are *contractual terms* between the hoster and the client about *reliability* of the hosting service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft publishes a set of documents describing windows azure security which you can find here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff934690.aspx

Do you have a specific security concern?